# Problem with Update query in Mysql with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

1. [see the screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aslxb.jpg)
2. [see the 2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw2jI.jpg)
3. [see the 3rd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4RgW.jpg)

Okay so I am building a project on java and mysql, I am stuck at this point that I have to update a data which is in MySql but from my java gui application, I've executed that update command from MySql command line client

```sql
update user set bldu = 50 where userid = 1001;
```

and it's working perfectly fine there but from my java application on clicking on assigned jbutton it says:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userid= 1001' at line 1

Please help me..!

Comment: show your java query and exception. edit it

Comment: Probably the terminating semicolon

Comment: Post code, errors, table descriptions etc as text and not images of text.

Comment: you have not posted java query syntax yet

Comment: got it... you forgot space before your where clause in java query

Comment: Don't build your sql queries dynamically: use `PreparedStatement`s instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
String query = "update user SET bldu = " + bldut + " WHERE userid = " + uid + ";";
```

use this one instead of your old query may be it is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it now i've just ran that program now it says "Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()"

Comment: Use executeUpdate() there

Comment: i have used that in codes you can see

```java
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

but it's still giving that error..

Answer (score 2):

In your first screenshot you must add a space before `WHERE` clause:

```
String query = "UPDATE user SET bdlu = " + bldut + "WHERE userid = " + uid + ";";
```

So your query will be interpretated as:

```
UPDATE user SET bdlu = 50WHERE userid = 1001
```

So you'll raise a syntax error.

Then you'll have the following query:

```
String query = "UPDATE user SET bdlu = " + bldut + " WHERE userid = " + uid + ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet in your code.

```
String query = "update user SET bldu = " + bldut + " WHERE userid = " + uid + ";";
Statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
Statement.executeUpdate();
```

by looking at your code you cannot store results of update query in resultSet the executeUpdate() only return 0 or 1 for success and failure of Update.

Comment: okay Onkar as soon as i replaced this snippet with mine, whole lot of errors poped up now, i have to use "rs.getString" too to get the updated results from db to show here  in the jTable1 too..

Answer (score 0):

Okay i guys i have figured out something that it is working i mean this program is updating the data stored in mysql from netbeans via jdbc but it won't stop showing that error message like:

"Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()"

everytime i click one that assigned jButton..! but i checked the database the value i want to change is being changed but then why it is showing this error..?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in your java file, do changes according to your file. your issue is you are using the same query in a result set that already uses for the update

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdb", "root", "root");

try {

```
    String query = "update user SET bldu = " + bldut+ " WHERE userid = " + uid + ";";           
    // create the java mysql update preparedstatement
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

    query = "select * from user  WHERE userid = " + uid +";";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
    while (rs.next()) {
        // Retrieve by column name
        String userid = rs.getString("userid");
        String userfname = rs.getString("userfname");
        // all your column
        // Display values
        System.out.print("userid: " + userid);
    }
    // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    // finally block used to close resources
    try {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }// end finally try
}// end try
```